# Can I call this dialog in Xamarin.IOS?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

Is this a built-in dialog that can be called in IOS or would you compose it manually using UIActivityViewController?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`ActionSheet` from `UIAlertController`

```
// Create a new Alert Controller
                UIAlertController actionSheetAlert = UIAlertController.Create("Action Sheet", "Select an item from below", UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet);

                // Add Actions
                actionSheetAlert.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("Item One",UIAlertActionStyle.Default, (action) => Console.WriteLine ("Item One pressed.")));

                actionSheetAlert.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("Item Two",UIAlertActionStyle.Default, (action) => Console.WriteLine ("Item Two pressed.")));

                actionSheetAlert.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("Item Three",UIAlertActionStyle.Default, (action) => Console.WriteLine ("Item Three pressed.")));

                actionSheetAlert.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("Cancel",UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, (action) => Console.WriteLine ("Cancel button pressed.")));

                // Required for iPad - You must specify a source for the Action Sheet since it is
                // displayed as a popover
                UIPopoverPresentationController presentationPopover = actionSheetAlert.PopoverPresentationController;
                if (presentationPopover!=null) {
                    presentationPopover.SourceView = this.View;
                    presentationPopover.PermittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection.Up;
                }

                // Display the alert
                this.PresentViewController(actionSheetAlert,true,null);
```

More info: https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/standard_controls/alertcontroller/

Comment: In other words, this is not built-in?

Comment: It is built in!

Comment: the possibility to create a dialog is built-in. But the exact dialog with the exact items "Call", "Send message", ...  Needs to be done manually. That's what you means by built-in, I guess?

Comment: Aaa, I understand now what you mean.. The "exact dialog" it's "managed" by iOS -> when an user long tap on an phone number, is detected by the OS and it prompts whit this dialog. You can implement an UITextView with DataDetectors - phone number, with behaviour non editable; the user must long tap on the phone number...

Comment: That was the solution. Thank you!